# "Invalid token specified" error when adding query params to url

Tags: authentication, ember.js, parameters

Using Ember.JS v3.8:
When trying to load a URL in a fresh browser with no session data:
If I try to access the page like:

```
https://www.example.com/mystuff/resourceid/usage-summary
```

This loads just fine.
But if I try something like:

```
https://www.example.com/mystuff/resourceid/usage-summary?param=myparam
```

I get:
`{message: "Invalid token specified"}` error thrown by jquery.
I have other places in my app where query params in the URL works just fine. It is one specific route that would not accept them.

The session data is initialized with an empty token {}. But I get the same results if I init it with null or no token data at all. And again - it works just fine unless I have query params.

Note: I have my own custom authenticator that extends ember-simple-auth. I've put a breakpoint in the init() - it never gets hit.

Anything would help! Thanks!

Comment: could you make an [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: I was using the parameters in the controller's init(), which was too early and caused the error. Once I moved it to setup(), everything is well.